# Adding my own buttons to a Bootgrid table using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-bootgrid

I am using JQuery Bootgrid for my table display, pagination, search, etc.  What I do not like about it are the command buttons, I just want to add simple html buttons to my tables such as:

```
echo "<td><a href='expensereport.php?source=editexpenses&p_id=$expenseID'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-icon' type='button'><span class='zmdi zmdi-edit'></span></button></a>";
```

This approach works great until I use

```
<table id="data-table">
```

which tuirns on bootgrid.  Bootgrid will not display the button, at all in my table.  Does anyone know how to turn off the bootgrid command buttons so I can add my own?  My buttons work great until I add bootgrid, which is refusing to display them in my tables.  Thank you for your help I am new to Bootgrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into using [Formatters](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/documentation#formatters).

Create a column were each cell contains your `$expenseID`.

Make sure that `data-column-id` is set on the expense id column head. For this example we will set it to `data-column-id="expenseId"`. You can hide this column entirely from view by adding `data-visible-in-selection='false'` and `data-visible='false'` to the column head too.

In the column head for your "actions" you will also need to specify the formatter you would like to use by passing `data-formatter`. In this case I have named the formatter function `expenseReportEdit` so we will use `data-formatter="expenseReportEdit"`.

Your HTML markup for the table head will be something like this..

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-column-id="expenseId" data-identifier='true' data-visible-in-selection='false' data-visible='false'>Expense ID</th>
        <th data-column-id="expenseActions" data-formatter="expenseReportEdit">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Then create your formatter function like so..

```
$("#yourTableId").bootgrid({
    formatters: {                    
        expenseReportEdit: function (column, row) {
            return "<a href=\"expensereport.php?source=editexpenses&p_id=" + row.expenseId + "\"><button class='btn btn-primary btn-icon' type='button'><span class='zmdi zmdi-edit'></span></button></a>";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What if I have multiple buttons, one for delete, one for add, one for edit?